# Tailwind CSS does not work with react app - no affect

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a react website using
`npx create-react-app myapp` 
`cd my app`
later i followed the steps as per mentioned on tailwind css that are as followed:
`npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`
and then
`npx tailwindcss init -p`
followed by this i added the following statement to tailwindconfig:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

later added the following to index .css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

my app.js looked like following:

```
import './index.css'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className='text-orange-500' >Navbar</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

still the tailwind is not taking any affect please help
folder structure is as followed;
[image]

the browser displays as it is
[image]

Comment: How is your app folder structure?

Comment: I assume you are using the latest versions of everything? Did you encounter any errors while installing packages? Have you restarted the dev server? If you reference other CSS inside `index.css` does it work?

Comment: What does your rendered source look like? What does your browser dev tools tell you?

Comment: @DavidRubin added the screenshot

Comment: @mxmissile added screenshot

Comment: @BhaveshDaswani added screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be having issue with tailwind.config.js can you try the below tailwind.config.js, In Create React App, the components are stored in src directory and you are targeting specific to pages and components directory, so going with .src/pages/**/*, .src/pages/*, .src/components/**/*, .src/components/*, may work you, Give it a try.

```
    module.exports = {
      content: [
        ".src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        ".src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
".src/components/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
".src/pages/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      ],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
```

Comment: no still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue the issue was in tailwind config and along with that i deleted the postcss file. The new tailwind config:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      md: '768px',
      // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

      lg: '1024px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

      xl: '1280px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }

      '2xl': '1536px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

this worked for me still i am confused over the fact why it happened but anyways its working now